# Correct construction of AST in C

Tags: c, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer

I am trying to implement a mathematical expression parser that receives a string as input and eventually outputs a conditional representation to the console.
I have already implemented a similar working program in Python:

```py
def term(self):
     result = self.factor()
     while self.current_token.type in (MUL, DIV):
         token = self.current_token
         if token.type == MUL:
             self.eat(MUL)
             result = result * self.factor()
         elif token.type == DIV:
             self.eat(DIV)
             result = result / self.factor()
```

But now, due to my inexperience in the C language, I am having some problems.
I have attached a sketch of the future program, and in it I am interested in the `parser_term` function.

```c
AST_T* parser_term(Parser_T* parser) {
    AST_T* result;

    while (parser->current_token->type == TOKEN_MUL
           || parser->current_token->type == TOKEN_DIV) {
        if (parser->current_token->type == TOKEN_MUL) {
            parser_eat(parser, TOKEN_MUL);
        } else if (parser->current_token->type == TOKEN_DIV) {
            parser_eat(parser, TOKEN_DIV);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

How should I create a new binary operation node? This is probably a somewhat stupid question, but I hope you can help me figure it out.

I will also be glad if you point out to me other mistakes, which may be enough in my code.

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//============================ LEXICAL ANALYSIS ============================================

//---------------------------- Token -------------------------------------------------------
typedef struct TOKEN_STRUCT
{
    enum
    {
        TOKEN_INTEGER,
        TOKEN_PLUS, TOKEN_MINUS,
        TOKEN_MUL,  TOKEN_DIV,
        TOKEN_LBRA, TOKEN_RBRA,
        TOKEN_EOF
    } type;

    char* value;

} Token_T;

Token_T* init_token(int type, char* value)
{
    Token_T* token = calloc(1, sizeof(struct TOKEN_STRUCT));
    token->type = type;
    token->value = value;

    return token;
}

void token_debug_print(Token_T* token)
{
    printf(
        "Token( type: '%d', value: '%s' )\n",
        token->type, token->value
    );

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//---------------------------- Lexer -------------------------------------------------------
typedef struct LEXER_STRUCT
{
    char current_char;
    unsigned int position;
    char* content;

} Lexer_T;

Lexer_T* init_lexer(char* content)
{
    Lexer_T* lexer = calloc(1, sizeof(struct LEXER_STRUCT));
    lexer->content = content;
    lexer->position = 0;
    lexer->current_char = lexer->content[lexer->position];

    return lexer;
}

void lexer_advance(Lexer_T* lexer)
{
    if (lexer->current_char != '\0')
    {
        lexer->position += 1;
        lexer->current_char = lexer->content[lexer->position];
    }
}

void lexer_skip_whitespace(Lexer_T* lexer)
{
    while (lexer->current_char == ' ')
    {
        lexer_advance(lexer);
    }
}

char* lexer_get_current_char_as_string(Lexer_T* lexer)
{
    char* stringus = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    stringus[0] = lexer->current_char;
    stringus[1] = '\0';

    return stringus;
}

Token_T* lexer_get_digit(Lexer_T* lexer)
{
    char* lexem = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    lexem[0] = '\0';

    while (lexer->current_char >= '0' && lexer->current_char <= '9')
    {
        char* part = lexer_get_current_char_as_string(lexer);
        lexem = realloc(lexem, (strlen(lexem) + strlen(part) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcat(lexem, part);
        lexer_advance(lexer);

    }

    return init_token(TOKEN_INTEGER, lexem);
}

Token_T* lexer_get_op(Lexer_T* lexer)
{
    switch (lexer->current_char)
    {
        case '+':
            lexer_advance(lexer);
            return init_token(TOKEN_PLUS, "+");

        case '-':
            lexer_advance(lexer);
            return init_token(TOKEN_MINUS, "-");

        case '*':
            lexer_advance(lexer);
            return init_token(TOKEN_MUL, "*");

        case '/':
            lexer_advance(lexer);
            return init_token(TOKEN_DIV, "/");
    }
}

Token_T* lexer_get_next_token(Lexer_T* lexer)
{
    while (lexer->current_char != '\0')
    {
        if (lexer->current_char == ' ')
            lexer_skip_whitespace(lexer);

        else if (lexer->current_char >= '0' && lexer->current_char <= '9')
            return lexer_get_digit(lexer);

        else if (lexer->current_char == '+' || lexer->current_char == '-' ||
                 lexer->current_char == '*' || lexer->current_char == '/')
            return lexer_get_op(lexer);

        else if (lexer->current_char == '(')
        {
            lexer_advance(lexer);
            return init_token(TOKEN_LBRA, "(");
        }

        else if (lexer->current_char == ')')
        {
            lexer_advance(lexer);
            return init_token(TOKEN_RBRA, ")");
        }
    }

    return init_token(TOKEN_EOF, "\\0");
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//=========================================================================================

//============================ SYNTAX ANALYSIS ============================================
//---------------------------- AST --------------------------------------------------------
typedef struct AST_STRUCT
{
    enum{
        AST_NUMBER,
        AST_BINOP,
        AST_PAREN_EXPR
    } type;

    char* number_value;

    char* bin_operator;
    struct AST_STRUCT* left;
    struct AST_STRUCT* right;

    struct AST_STRUCT* paren_expr;

} AST_T;

AST_T* init_AST(int type)
{
    AST_T* ast = calloc(1, sizeof(struct AST_STRUCT));
    ast->type = type;

    return ast;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//---------------------------- Parser -----------------------------------------------------
typedef struct PARSER_STRUCT
{
    Lexer_T* lexer;
    Token_T* current_token;

} Parser_T;

Parser_T* init_parser(Lexer_T* lexer)
{
    Parser_T* parser = calloc(1, sizeof(struct PARSER_STRUCT));
    parser->lexer = lexer;
    parser->current_token = lexer_get_next_token(parser->lexer);

    return parser;
}

AST_T* parser_factor(Parser_T* parser);
AST_T* parser_term(Parser_T* parser);
AST_T* parser_expr(Parser_T* parser);

void parser_eat(Parser_T* parser, int type)
{
   if (parser->current_token->type == type)
   {
       parser->current_token = lexer_get_next_token(parser->lexer);
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Unexpected token");
       exit(0);
   }
}

AST_T* parser_expr(Parser_T* parser)
{

}

AST_T* parser_factor(Parser_T* parser)
{
    if (parser->current_token->type == TOKEN_INTEGER)
    {
        AST_T* node = init_AST(TOKEN_INTEGER);
        node->number_value = parser->current_token->value;
        parser_eat(parser, TOKEN_INTEGER);

        return node;
    }

}

AST_T* parser_term(Parser_T* parser)
{
    AST_T* result;

    while (parser->current_token->type == TOKEN_MUL || parser->current_token->type == TOKEN_DIV)
    {
        if (parser->current_token->type == TOKEN_MUL)
        {
            parser_eat(parser, TOKEN_MUL);
        }
        else if (parser->current_token->type == TOKEN_DIV)
        {
            parser_eat(parser, TOKEN_DIV);
        }
    }

    return result;

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//=========================================================================================

//============================ VISITOR ====================================================
typedef struct VISITOR_STRUCT
{

} Visitor_T;

Visitor_T* init_visitor(AST_T* ast)
{
    Visitor_T* visitor = calloc(1, sizeof(struct VISITOR_STRUCT));

    return visitor;
}

void visitor_visit_number(Visitor_T* visitor, AST_T* node)
{
    printf("Number {\n");
    printf(" %s\n", node->number_value);
    printf("}\n");

}

void visitor_visit_bin_op(Visitor_T* visitor, AST_T* node)
{
    printf("Binop {\n");
    visitor_visit(visitor, node->left);
    visitor_visit(visitor, node->right);
    printf("\n}\n");

}

void visitor_visit_paren_expr(Visitor_T* visitor, AST_T* node)
{
    visitor_visit(visitor, node);

}

void visitor_visit(Visitor_T* visitor, AST_T* ast)
{
    if (ast->type == AST_NUMBER)
    {
        visitor_visit_number(visitor, ast);
    }
    else if (ast->type == AST_BINOP)
    {
        visitor_visit_bin_op(visitor, ast);
    }
    else if (ast->type == AST_PAREN_EXPR)
    {
        visitor_visit_paren_expr(visitor, ast);
    }
}
//=========================================================================================
int main()
{
    char* code = "77 * 12 * 9 * 2";
    Lexer_T* lexer = init_lexer(code);

    Parser_T* parser = init_parser(lexer);
    AST_T* ast = parser_term(parser);

    Visitor_T* visitor = init_visitor(ast);
    visitor_visit(visitor, ast);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to get the factor value first and add it to the node, and then continue parsing the expression, but this only confused me.
I expect that this program will be able to process similar binary operations and turn them into one AST .

Comment: First and foremost, for whatever compiler you are using, enable warnings.  On gcc or clang, that will be `-Wall -Wextra` and if you want to get crazy, `-Wpedantic`.  That will point out a handful of things already.  Does `parser_term` work in python as you expect?  If so, could you post that code?

Comment: To maybe answer the question though... If this is a recursive descent parser, you will want to consume the *less* priority operations first (like + and -).  That way, you can split the expression on those first.   For example, `2 * 5 + 7 * 3`.  You want to consume and split on the `+` *first*. Then you can descend into parsing `2 * 5` and `7 * 3` individually.

Comment: I copied the Python `term()` function into the question itself.  But it's not clear to me how that's doing the same job that you want the C function to do.  It looks like it's computing a value, perhaps based on an AST that has already been constructed, not building an AST.

Comment: Are you required to write your lexer from scratch?  Perhaps you are, but if not, then generating code for lexers is exactly what the traditional `lex` program and its GNU work-alike `flex` are for.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's not exactly what we need.
I can assume that on python it should look something like this
    
```class BinOp(AST):
class Num(AST):

class Parser():
        
    def term(self):
        node = self.factor()

        while self.current_token.type in (MUL, DIV):
            token = self.current_token
            if token.type == MUL:
                self.eat(MUL)
            elif token.type == DIV:
                self.eat(DIV)
            node = BinOp(left=node, op=token, right=self.factor())
        return node```

Comment: Please stop posting multiline Python fragments into the comments.  They are just about impossible to read.  If the question would be clarified or otherwise improved by adding more Python code or editing what is already there, then use the "Edit" link to make such changes.

Comment: Note also that if you want to implement the usual arithmetic precedence rules, such that, for example, 1 + 2 * 3 evaluates to 7 instead of 9, then you need to differentiate between different kinds of binary operations.  It looks like you *could* do that via `AST_T.bin_operator`, but I anticipate that it would be easier to separate your binary operators into different kinds by precedence level, say `ADDITIVE_OP` and `MULTIPLICATIVE_OP`.

Comment: sorry, I still can't get used to using this site. And with regard to using a ready-made solution such as lex or flex, this is  possible, since this project has no special requirements. I don't want to use ready-made solutions because I want to understand for myself how it works and not feel so stupid and helpless)

Comment: I think I started to understand in which direction regard  should move . Thank you very much

Comment: As you like.  But note that being able to use higher-level tools such as Flex effectively, makes you better equipped, not stupid or helpless.  On the other hand, it would be more for you to learn, so perhaps not the thing to tackle right now.

Comment: For reference, I wrote a parser for TSQL that I wrote to replace an ANTLR generated parser.  [Here](https://github.com/jasonKercher/sqlparse/blob/master/sqlparse.c#L355) is a link to the expression parsing function.  It probably has bugs in it, as I haven't gotten back to it, but the main idea works.  You are welcome to copy whatever you want from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one explicit question here is this:

> How should I create a new binary operation node?

You need an object that is created at need but whose lifetime is not automatically limited to the function execution in which it begins.  This combination requires dynamic allocation.  (You get that automatically in Python, all the time, but in C, you have to ask for it.)  For example:

```
    AST_T *result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
```

As a matter of best practices, you should always verify that the allocation succeeded before trying to use the allocated object.  If not, you should fall back to some kind of alternative or recovery operation or, more commonly, just fail.  In a *program*, as opposed to a library, it's reasonable to fail by printing a diagnostic and terminating.  For example:

```
    if (result == NULL) {
        fputs("fatal error: memory allocation failure\n", stderr);
        abort();
    }
```

But the allocations in your program are very unlikely to fail unless something else is badly wrong.

Supposing that the allocation succeed, you will want to set the members of the new object appropriately.  Maybe something along these lines:

```
    result->type = /* as appropriate */; // ...
    result->number_value = NULL;
    result->bin_operator = // ...
    result->left = NULL; // probably something other than NULL in some cases
    result->right = NULL;
    result->paren_expr = NULL;  // WTH?
```

Ultimately, you will need to either return the pointer to the new node (which seems to be what you anticipate doing) or maybe assign it to a member of the parser.  Or both.  These are easy.  For example,

```
    return result;
```

> I will also be glad if you point out to me other mistakes

I'm afraid that's too broad an ask for SO.  But do turn up your compiler's warnings and pay attention to them.  At your level of experience, you should assume that every warning describes a problem that will make your program work incorrectly.